# Problems loading XML file (url cannot load) on local machine

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to have my flash application interpret an XML file. My code looks like:

```
function onFinish(success_boolean, results_obj, xml)
{
    if (success_boolean)
    {
        play ();
    } // end if
} // End of the function
Stage.align = "MC";
Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
url = "25358";
_root.cacheKiller = "true";
stop ();
var parsed_obj = {};
var unCash = new Date().getTime();
if (_root.cacheKiller == "true")
{
    fileToLoad = url + "_main.xml?cacheKiller=" + unCash;
    fileToLoad = url + "_main.xml";
}
else
{
    fileToLoad = url + "_main.xml";
} // end else if
gs.dataTransfer.XMLParser.load(fileToLoad, onFinish, parsed_obj);
_root.emp.useHandCursor = 0;
_root.mus = 1;
_root.n = 1;
_root.num = 1;
```

the output i get is:

Error opening URL 'file:///C|/try/25358undefined'

Does anyone have any idea why i can't access this file? I've verified that the URL works.

Comment: Try specifying type for `unCash` as say `uint`, otherwise you're risking issues with "String+whatever" operation to provide weird results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong url. I mean that `fileToLoad` contains a wrong value. Try to trace this variable.